# Про медия запросы

Tags: media

У меня такой вопрос: когда я задаю @media и меняю font-size для body, почему автоматически не меняются все шрифты, которые заданы c помощью rem?

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1440px) {
    body{
      font-size: 16px
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    body{
      font-size: 12px
    }
}
```

Меняются только элементы, которые наследуют значение body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что `rem` - это не `body`, а `html`.

Comment: вы о чем? я про единицу измерения

Comment: @ESargsyan, и я про неё. У тебя селектор неправильный.

Comment: Аа, нашел более подробное обьяснение. Вы правы. Все понял, спасибо!

Comment: @ESargsyan, если ответ решил проблему, прими его нажатием на галочку слева от него.